# jQuery and CouchDBX - _all_docs - HTTP 200 but no data is returned to success function

Tags: jquery, couchdb

I can't access my CouchDB server ([CouchDBX](http://janl.github.com/couchdbx/)) using a jQuery AJAX call.

I am able to access my demo database at `localhost:5984/helloworld/_all_docs` through browsers (tested with FireFox, Chrome and Safari). But when I do a simple AJAX call using jQuery I get no data returned.

The requests completes with code 200.

Here's what my AJAX call looks like:

```
$(function ()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            console.log("error", xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);
        },
        global: false,
        success: function (data, textStatus, xmlHttpRequest)
        {
            console.log("success", data, textStatus, xmlHttpRequest);
        },
        timeout: 3000,
        url: "http://localhost:5984/helloworld/_all_docs"
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

Screenshots of FireBug console:

http://grab.by/6fkS

http://grab.by/6fkX

http://grab.by/6fkY

Comment: Can you give us the output of `console.log("success", data, textStatus, xmlHttpRequest);`?

Comment: Are you certain Safari wasn't working? It is usually more permissive about cross-domain requests when hosting from the filesystem (which I assume you're doing). I just tried, and Safari returns two test documents I created (using CouchDBX).

Answer (score 0):

I think your browser is blocking the data.

[XmlHttpRequest error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

Comment: Yep. Just ran your code in Chrome, which threw an error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:5984/db/_all_docs?_=1283713669140. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: So I need to get a HTTP server running, and run my pages there instead of just opening them from disk? Would that solve my same-origin-policy issues?

Comment: Upload them as document attachments and hit them from the browser that way. (This is how CouchApps do it.) That way you're actually serving pages and data from the same Origin.